# I am trying to repeat a loop,but adding labels didnt help .Below i have mentioned the basic code,where i want to display till next page is available

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to repeat a loop, but adding labels did not help .Below I have mentioned the basic code, where I want to display till next page is available.

As mentioned below, after clicking on nextPage, I want to get the count for `g` incremented and also get all the Table contents. kindly help.

```
public void GetTableData(String TableRowXpath,WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException, InvalidFormatException, IOException{
      WebElement nextPage=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='ldtable_next' and @class='paginate_button next']"));
      //WebElement nextPageNotAvailable=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='ldtable_next' and @class='paginate_button next disabled']"));
      int g=1;
      if(nextPage.isDisplayed()){
          List<WebElement> Rowlist=driver.findElements(By.xpath(TableRowXpath));

          int RowIndex=1;

          for(WebElement rowElement:Rowlist)
          {
              List<WebElement> columnlist=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
              int ColumnIndex=1;
              int h=0;
              for(WebElement colElement:columnlist)
              {
                  System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "
                  + colElement.getText());
                  String j=colElement.getText();
                  ExcelLib e=new ExcelLib();
                  e.createRow("Sheet3", h); 
                  e.setExcelData("Sheet3",h, g, j);
                  ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;
                  h++;
              }
              g++;
              RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
          }
         nextPage.click();
         Thread.sleep(5000);     
      }        
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your if clause to either

```
do{//Code goes here} while(nextPage.isDisplayed());
```

or

```
while(nextPage.isDisplayed()){//Code goes here}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution,but the problem still persits. As in,suppose 1st page data is limited to <10 rows,so nextPage webelement won't be present to click and will get "no such element " present exception.And thereby code fails.

Simmilarly,if i use while(nextPage.isDisplayed()),then after clicking on next page,code will fail again as no more navigation button is present for it to navigate and it doesnt take the row data even. Both the above things i tried,but it didnt work

Comment: you can do one more thing in the condition part every time fetch the element. something like while(driver.findelement(by.locator).isDisplayed())

Answer (score 0):

below code can be used to get table data
 public void GetTableData(String TableRowXpath,WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException, InvalidFormatException, IOException{

```
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  String s=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ldtable_info']")).getText();
  String number=s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("of") + 3, s.lastIndexOf(" "));
  int c=Integer.parseInt(number);
  System.out.println("total entries"+c);
  int g=1;
  int RowIndex=1;
  if(c>10){
      try{

     WebElement nextPage=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='ldtable_next' and @class='paginate_button next']"));
  //WebElement nextPageNotAvailable=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='ldtable_next' and @class='paginate_button next disabled']"));

while(nextPage.isDisplayed()){
      List<WebElement> Rowlist=driver.findElements(By.xpath(TableRowXpath));

      for(WebElement rowElement:Rowlist)
            {
        List<WebElement> columnlist=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
      int ColumnIndex=1;
      int h=0;
      for(WebElement colElement:columnlist)
                {
      System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+colElement.getText());
      String j=colElement.getText();
      ExcelLib e=new ExcelLib();
      e.createRow("Sheet3", h); 
      e.setExcelData("Sheet3",h, g, j);
      ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;
      h++;
                }
      g++;
      RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
            }


     nextPage.click();
     Thread.sleep(5000);

  } 
      }
      catch(Exception ei){
          List<WebElement> Rowlist=driver.findElements(By.xpath(TableRowXpath));

          for(WebElement rowElement:Rowlist)
                {
            List<WebElement> columnlist=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
          int ColumnIndex=1;
          int h=0;
          for(WebElement colElement:columnlist)
                    {
          System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+colElement.getText());
          String j=colElement.getText();
          ExcelLib e=new ExcelLib();
          e.createRow("Sheet3", h); 
          e.setExcelData("Sheet3",h, g, j);
          ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;
          h++;
                    }
          g++;
          RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
                }

      }
  }
  else{
      List<WebElement> Rowlist=driver.findElements(By.xpath(TableRowXpath));


      for(WebElement rowElement:Rowlist)
            {
        List<WebElement> columnlist=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
      int ColumnIndex=1;
      int h=0;
      for(WebElement colElement:columnlist)
                {
      System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+colElement.getText());
      String j=colElement.getText();
      ExcelLib e=new ExcelLib();
      e.createRow("Sheet3", h); 
      e.setExcelData("Sheet3",h, g, j);
      ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;
      h++;
                }
      g++;
      RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
            }

  }
```

}